# Custom Formatting of Grouping header having the data of type DateTime

Tags: datetime, jqgrid, grouping, drag

I am using [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vRtKS/96/) to create drag and drop grouping for jqGrid

I have a `DateTime` as a grouped column.

The formater for the column is

```
sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/y H:i' }
```

The date is displayed as "03/07/14 09:22" in the column (as usual) 
but the header is being displayed as "Date: /Date(1404372141000)/"
(in the previous version it was being displayed as "03/07/14 09:22" [Older Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tpeczek/vRtKS/))

I could use something like:

```js
function customFormatDisplayField(displayValue, value, colModel, index, grp) {
    if (colModel.name == "Date")
    {
       // displayValue = ConvertedValue;
    }
    return getColumnHeaderByName.call(this, colModel.name) + " : " + displayValue;
};
```

but I don't know how I convert `1404372141000` (or `/Date(1404372141000)/`) back into `03/07/14 09:22` or how `1404372141000` is being generated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you need just modify a little the code of `customFormatDisplayField` function. You can call `formatter` from the corresponding column. The code below will work not with all formaters, but the most one:

```js
var customFormatDisplayField = function (displayValue, value, colModel, index, grp) {
    var val = displayValue;
    if (typeof colModel.formatter === "string") {
        val = $.fn.fmatter.call(this, colModel.formatter, value, {
            colModel: colModel,
            gid: this.id
        });
    }
    return getColumnHeaderByName.call(this, colModel.name) + ": " + val;
}
```

The modified JSFiddle demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vRtKS/99/).

Comment: Thanks everything works great now. Thanks for the help